# Does Google's Activity Recognition works on every Android device supporting API higher than 8?

Tags: android, google-play-services, activity-recognition

I'm trying to launch any android ActivityRecognition example but have no success after couple of days. I installed Google Services, successfully connected to LocationServices client, installed the latest SDK, placed intent service in my app, turned on Location Services in device preferences but still - no update, no calls of onHandleIntent (btw, I placed breakpoint in the intent service's constructor and it seems that application never come there: is it normal?). 
My device is XPERIA M. I tried the following code from android dev guide: http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/ActivityRecognition.zip
and from here: https://github.com/diegofigueroa/activity-recognition-sample

All code was used unaffected, except adding a meta-data tag:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Comment: you've followed the whole flow as discussed in http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html ?

Comment: @Ryan Yeah, I followed

Comment: What does [GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)) return?

Comment: @ianhanniballake true, I mean ConnectionResult.SUCCESS

Answer (score 0):

Closed. Solved by re-install of the Google Play Services on the phone. Weird stuff, thank you all.